# Understanding Python Class Output

Tags: python, class

I'm attempting to figure out the output from the python program below. The portion of the program that is most confusing to me is the print statement in main `print(c2.clown(c1.clown(2)))` what exactly is happening in this line? My prediction for the result of this program was as follows:

> Clowning around now.
>
> Create a Bozo from 3
>
> Create a Bozo from 4
>
> Clown 3
>
> 18
>
> 3 + 6 = return 9
>
> Clown 4
>
> 32
>
> 4 + 8 = return 12
>
> print(c2.clown(c1.clown(2)) = 12 * 2 = 24 ????

But the output / answer is:

> Clowning around now.
>
> Create a Bozo from: 3
>
> Create a Bozo from: 4
>
> Clown 2
>
> 12
>
> Clown 8
>
> 64
>
> 16

```
 class Bozo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        print("Create a Bozo from:", value)
        self.value = 2 * value


    def clown(self, x):
        print("Clown", x)
        print(x * self.value)
        return x + self.value


def main():
    print("Clowning around now.")
    c1 = Bozo(3)
    c2 = Bozo(4)
    print(c2.clown(c1.clown(2)))

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# c1.clown(2) works as :
def clown(self, x):  #x=2, c1.value = 6
    print("Clown", x) #print("Clown, 2")
    print(x * self.value) #print(12) 12=6*2
    return x + self.value #return 2+6=8 

# c2.clown(8) works as :
def clown(self, x):  #x=8, c1.value = 8
    print("Clown", x) #print("Clown, 8")
    print(x * self.value) #print(64) 64=8*8
    return x + self.value #return 8+8=16

print(16)
```

Comment: @cricket why is c1.value = 6? and does x = 2 because print(c2.clown(c1.clown(2)) ?

Comment: @user35 because `c1 = Bozo(3)`... Multiply 3 by 2. X equals 2 (the first time) because that's the parameter to the clown function

Comment: @user3574939 You probably haven't get the difference between instantiating a new object verus a genral function call. When you call `c1=Bozo(3)`, you are creating a new object of `Bozo` class, and the method `__init__()` will be called to do some initializing stuff(assigning value = 2 * input). While  `clown()` is a class method. And by chaining the function calls, they will get executed from inside to out.

Answer (score 1):

Inside out...

`c1.clown(2)` runs and returns before anything.

It prints Clown 2, then `2 * c1.value = 2 * 6 = 12`

That returns `2 + c1.value = 2 + 6 = 8` , which is passed to `c2.clown()`

`4 + 8` is never ran. It's `8 + 8` because the clown value is multiplied by 2